# SCRIPT70: Permissions Denied

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have been banging my head against a wall with this for a few hours now.

I have checked all of our Facebook applications in IE and I get the following error when the permissions dialogue box has been accepted:

SCRIPT70: Permission denied 
all.js, line 22 character 4321

I have looked at past posts but they seemed to have happened a while back and Facebook have said that the issue is closed. It seems to have re-surfaced.

I am using the correct https code and it all works fine in Chrome/Safari/Firefox.

Has anyone got any ideas on this ?

Many thanks

Comment: Where does the problem occur?

Comment: It happens after the permission dialogue has been accepted?

Comment: How are you triggering the dialog? do you have a callback function defined? (if you're using the Javascript SDK)

Comment: FB.login(function(response){if (response.authResponse){//code here}, {scope:'publish_actions,publish_stream,user_likes,user_birthday'});

Answer (score 1):

The channelUrl solution works fine except in one specific case.  If you have a script on your page that shortens the document.domain, then the file you create for the channelUrl must also shorten the document.domain to match.

For instance, if my host page is "foo.bar.com" and I have JavaScript shorten the document.domain to "bar.com" (which is legal, not advised, but legal), then the file I specify in channelUrl must do the same.

I know that Facebook states the file for channelUrl must contain just one line and that must be the script tag they specify, but that is really not the case.  As long as the script tag is in the head of the page your create, all is well.  Also, the document.domain shortening must happen before the Facebook code is called on both the host and channelUrl page.

I hope this helps others out, it sure was a pain to figure out on our site.  Oh, and we have to shorten our document.domain because of our ads server, so it's something we have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

One reported cause of this is if the channelURL you defined in the SDK init method doesn't match (protocol and domain) with the page load itself

i.e if you use a HTTP channel URL and the user is using HTTPS, or vice-versa, it may not work.

Try changing that and see if it helps. If you don't have a channelURL defined, you should add one (note that it's case sensitive).

Comment: Thanks for the response however I have added a channelUrl using this url: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/ and I still get the same problems.

Comment: I have just changed it to channelURL and still get the same error im afraid. It seems to load the dialogue, allow me to accept the permissions but the dialogue does not execute the callback when the permissions have been accepted. I have used this code on many other applications before without problems in IE so I can only assume something has been changed at API level, as our other applications are getting the same problems ?

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous comment - it was a mistake - it should be channelUrl - there was a mistake in the docs

Comment: If you can reproduce this reliably i recommend filing a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs - it sounds to me like this should be working for you

Comment: It happens across all of our apps in IE across several machines in the office so I will file a bug. Thanks.

Comment: I have just tried a machine running IE7 and it seems to work so I think it is IE9 specific.